# How do I set up Stencil PWA to work offline?

Tags: typescript, workbox, stenciljs

I am trying to build a PWA that works offline. I am using the Stencil PWA template, and it is working well online, but I can't seem to get it to work offline.

`stencil.config.ts`

```js
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

// https://stenciljs.com/docs/config

export const config: Config = {
  globalScript: 'src/global/app.ts',
  globalStyle: 'src/global/app.css',
  taskQueue: 'async',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: {
        globPatterns: [
          // Prefetch all local data
          '**/*.{js,css,json,html,ico,png}',
          // Prefetch all the api calls
          'https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/jsonrevexport.php?permission=yUp&autorun=1&what=*',
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

This is for a project [here](https://github.com/jhessin/rev-stencil). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this?

Update: I now cache the fetched data using @capacitor/store, so I no longer need to cache it in the app.

Comment: What happens if you remove the API from the glob patterns (since you're saving the result in the filesystem anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on your repo.

The URL in `globPatterns` seems to completely remove the precache manifest in `sw.js`. I'm not sure why but since you're saving the API results in the file system (IDB in PWA) you don't need the service worker to cache these requests so you can remove it.

After that the PWA works offline for me, with one exception: The SVG icons are not cached. The easiest way would be to add `,svg` to the first glob pattern but that would cache every single ionicon which might be overkill.

An alternative is to manually specify which icons you're using:

```
serviceWorker: {
  globPatterns: [
    // The basics to cache everything?
    '**/*.{js,css,json,html,ico,png}',
    'build/svg/{arrow-back-outline,home-outline,close-circle}.svg',
  ],
},
```

Just remember to update this whenever you add or remove a new icon.

Comment: The app still doesn't work offline. I'm trying to get it so it can be loaded completely (so people can save it to their home screen on mobile) offline - is that a pipe dream?

Comment: No, I got it to work offline on my Android phone with the changes I mentioned. Just loaded the page, waited till all resources were downloaded, installed to home screen, turned off wifi and opened it. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Hmm? Did you exit and relaunch the app? That is where I have the issue.

Comment: I tested on Android and swiped it away and opened it again from the home screen. Are you testing on iOS? Do you get any error message (like "could not load")?

Comment: I have been testing on iOS but I have the same problem on android. It will not load while offline.  Maybe it has to do with our versions of android/chrome?

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? I tested it on Android 9 and on an old iPad Air with iOS 12.4.3. On iOS I had to add to home screen and open the shortcut with internet connection to really save the content.

Comment: I’m on iOS 15 and when I try to open the app without internet I get “safari can’t open this page”. I borrowed my wife’s tablet to try on android and I just get a blank white screen. This is after it has been loaded once already mind you. Are you turning off Wi-Fi and on airplane mode?

Comment: Yes, I also just tested it in Chrome on Windows. Are you accessing it with https (a requirement for service workers)? Also, can you access the console output, maybe there's an error? I do see some JSON parse errors but the app still seems to work fine.

Comment: I have it published here, https://rev-offline-8go5g.ondigitalocean.app/. Works great but not offline.

Comment: OK, something weird is happening.. If I clone the repo and run `npm i && npm run build` it doesn't work offline but if I build it again it suddenly does. After the second build it also hashes the filename `app.css` to `p-*****.css`. Can you try that (and empty the `www` folder first)?

Comment: Okay - why does that work? Now I just need to figure out how to deploy it. I tried changing the build command on digitalocean to `yarn build && yarn build` but that didn't work.

Comment: Okay - it works offline on the computer, but not on the phone?